# Use string value from a cell to access worksheet of same name

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 worksheets: `Summary` and `SERVER-ONE`.

In cell `A5` on the Summary worksheet, I have added the value `SERVER-ONE`.

Next to it, in cell `B5`, I would like a formula that uses the value in `A5` to display the value of `G7` in the worksheet of the same name (`SERVER-ONE`).

I could manually use:

```
='SERVER-ONE'!G7
```

However I would like this to be dynamic, so I can easily add more worksheets.

I tried the obvious with no joy:

```
='A5'!G7
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use the formula `INDIRECT()`.

This basically takes a string and treats it as a reference. In your case, you would use:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!G7")
```

The double quotes are to show that what's inside are strings, and only `A5` here is a reference.

Answer (score 13):

You need `INDIRECT` function:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!G7")
```

Answer (score 5):

not sure if you solved your question, but I found this worked to increment the row number upon dragging.

```
= INDIRECT("'"&$A$5&"'!$G"&7+B1)
```

Where B1 refers to an index number, starting at 0.

So if you copy-drag both the index cell and the cell with the indirect formula, you'll increment the indirect.
You could probably create a more elegant counter with the Index function too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using INDIRECT, which if you drag the formula, it will pick up different cells from the target sheet accordingly. It uses R1C1 notation and is not limited to working only on columns A-Z.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$5&"'!R"&ROW()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

This version picks up the value from the target cell corresponding to the cell where the formula is placed. For example, if you place the formula in 'Summary'!B5 then it will pick up the value from 'SERVER-ONE'!B5, not 'SERVER-ONE'!G7 as specified in the original question. But you could easily add in offsets to the row and column to achieve the desired mapping in any case.

Answer (score 3):

By using the `ROW()` function I can drag this formula vertically. It can also be dragged horizontally since there is no `$` before the `D`.

```
= INDIRECT("'"&D$2&"'!$B"&ROW())
```

My layout has sheet names as column headers (`B2`, `C2`, `D2`, etc.) and maps multiple row values from Column `B` in each sheet.

Answer (score 2):

INDIRECT is the function you want to use. Like so:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!G7")
```

With INDIRECT you can build your formula as a text string.

Answer (score 1):

Guess @user3010492 tested it but I used this with fixed cell A5 --> $A$5 and fixed element of G7 --> $G7

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$5&"'!$G7")
```

Also works nested nicely in other formula if you enclose it in brackets.

Comment: Is it possible in this context to auto increment G7 (G8, G9, etc) upon grabbing the lower right corner of the cell and pulling down, but keeping A5 fixed?

Comment: @MartinSommervold No, you will have to calculate it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This will only work to column Z, but you can drag this horizontally and vertically.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$D$2&"'!"&CHAR((COLUMN()+64))&ROW())
```