# String value from a cell to access worksheet of same name with a COUNTIF Function?

Tags: vba, excel

I was looking at this:
[Use string value from a cell to access worksheet of same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899175/use-string-value-from-a-cell-to-access-worksheet-of-same-name?rq=1)

But I want to know how to do that with a CountIF function. 
My WorkSheets are named by the Codes in column A3-A12, and that could increase in time.

```
=COUNTIF('100'!H:H,$B$2)
```

is how I'm counting all records on Worksheet 100 with the same value as in B2 (it's a date).

How do I use =INDIRECT and CountIF together? something like,

`=INDIRECT(COUNTIF("'"&A4&"'!H:H,$B$2))`

That doesn't work, but hopefully you understand what I wish to do.

I'm not calculating this function on each worksheet, then using Indirect to grab the values, because everyday those worksheets are blanked. So the functions wouldn't stay as well.
But that might be what I have to do, unless I can think of a macro.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the indirect inside the first criterion of the countifs. You have it backwards.

Comment: I think you need this `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&A4&"'!H:H"),$B$2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a string that looks like the argument.  If:

```
=COUNTIF('100'!H:H,$B$2)
```

works, then so will:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'100'!H:H"),$B$2)
```

If we put the sheet-name in, say cell **D4**, then so will:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & D4 & "'!H:H"),$B$2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @SimonYo  Thanks for the feedback!