# Excel Formula | Can't take Sheet's name with SUMIFS

Tags: excel

`=SUMIFS(A1 & !G:G, A1 & !A:A, "PERIOD " & B3, A1 & !F:F, C3)`

A1 represent the Sheet's name that I type in A1 cell.
But it didn't work, Excel recognize it as a mathematical formula.

What I except is:

`=SUMIFS(SHEETNAME!G:G, A1 & SHEETNAME!A:A, "PERIOD " & B3, SHEETNAME!F:F, C3)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use string value from a cell to access worksheet of same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899175/use-string-value-from-a-cell-to-access-worksheet-of-same-name)

Comment: don't know the keyword sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a sheet's name dynamically you can use `INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!G1")`

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!G:G"), INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A:A"), "PERIOD " & B3, INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!F:F"), C3)
```