# Excel use range name as an argument to excel function

Tags: excel, function, arguments, range

[image: Excel example]

Let suppose I have several named ranges, P2017.01, P2017.02 and so on. These ranges hold values from year 2017 month 01, month 02, and so on. 
I want to sum the month values one-by-one. I want to construct the names of the ranges, and use these constructed names as a function argument. Example: the prefix 'P2017' is in B3, the index of the month is in C3. I concatenate B3&'.'&C3 and store the value to D3.

In E3 I want to =SUM(INDEX(P2017.01;0;2)), but instead of writing the name P2017.01 I want to acquire the name from the value of cell D3.

What should I write to E3 to do that?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16899175/1578604). You can use INDIRECT with named ranges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use string value from a cell to access worksheet of same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899175/use-string-value-from-a-cell-to-access-worksheet-of-same-name)

Comment: Indeed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following formula...

```
=SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT(D3),0,2))
```

Comma (,) or semicolon (;) depens on regional settings.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the daily brand new excel function today! :)

Comment: Glad to know it helps you.