# Including tab name in formula from cell

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference

Similarly to this thread I have found [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899175/use-string-value-from-a-cell-to-access-worksheet-of-same-name)...

I am trying to create various formulae looking across tabs with the tab names kept in cells.  My hyperlink function has been successful as:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"&B2&"'!A1","Click Here")
```

Where B2 represents a 2-3 character tab name of a person's initials (e.g. AA in this example).

However if I try this method with other formulae I am returning a #VALUE! error.  Can anyone help me with making this nested Index/Match function work dynamically from cell B1 rather than being fixed to the tab name "AA"?

```
=IF(OR(INDEX(AA!B:AH,MATCH(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11)+1,AA!B:B,0),2)="",INDEX(AA!B:AH,MATCH(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11)+1,AA!B:B,0),10)="",INDEX(AA!B:AH,MATCH(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11)+1,AA!B:B,0),14)="",INDEX(AA!B:AH,MATCH(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11)+1,AA!B:B,0),22)=""),"No","Yes")
```

Thanks in advance?
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyperlink function accepts a constructed string to use as the link and interprets it as a range address just as it would a true url. A formula cannot accept a constructed string address as a worksheet range reference but the INDIRECT function converts constructed strings to a usable worksheet range reference.

```
INDEX(AA!B:AH,MATCH(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),11)+1,AA!B:B,0),2)
```

... becomes,

```
INDEX(indirect(text(B2, "'@'!\B\:\H")), MATCH(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(), 11)+1, indirect(text(B2, "'@'!\B\:\B")), 0), 2)
```

With *AA* in B2, `text(B2, "'@'!\B\:\H")` becomes `'AA'!B:H`. I find it easier to take care of the wrapping `'` marks with a format mask.